# Turning off desktop integration in firefox

Tags: firefox

I used to be able to turn off the desktop integration in firefox by going to the general settings and unclicking the box that says "Prompt integration options." But I just reinstalled 14.04 on a new laptop (T420) and the firefox settings have changed. That option no longer appears anywhere, so I'm constantly getting these prompts asking if I want to install this or that website.

How can I shut this off?

Answer (score 1):

Cancel that, I was able to turn it off using the Unity Tweak tool.